# Overloading the indirection operator in c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, indirection

my problem is a simple one. I have a class template that holds a pointer to a dynamically allocated type. I want to overload the indirection operator so that referring to the class template instance with the -> operator I get redirected as if I use the pointer contained within directly.

```
template<class T>
class MyClass
 {
  T *ptr;
  ...
  // created dynamic resource for ptr in the constructor
 };
```

Create myclass of some type:

```
MyClass<SomeObject> instance;
```

So what I want is instead of having to type:

```
instance.ptr->someMemberMethod();
```

I simply type:

```
intance->someMemberMethod();
```

Even thou `instance` is not a pointer it behaves as if it is the pointer `instance` contains. How to bridge that gap by overloading the operator?

Comment: Modern C++ Design (Andrei Alexandrescu) has some really good info on the subject if you would like more depth.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can just overload `operator->` and `operator*`:

```
template<class T>
class MyClass
{
    T* ptr;

public:
    T* operator->() {
        return ptr;
    }

    // const version, returns a pointer-to-const instead of just a pointer to
    // enforce the idea of the logical constness of this object 
    const T* operator->() const {
        return ptr;
    }

    T& operator*() {
        return *ptr;
    }

    // const version, returns a const reference instead of just a reference
    // to enforce the idea of the logical constness of this object
    const T& operator*() const {
        return *ptr;
    }
};
```

Note that, due to a design decision by the creator of the language, you can't overload the `.` operator.

Also, you might think that `operator*` would overload the *multiplication* operator instead of the dereference operator. However, this is not the case, because the multiplication operator takes a single argument (while the dereference operator takes no arguments), and because of this, the compiler can tell which one is which.

Finally, note that `operator->` returns a pointer but `operator*` returns a reference. It's easy to accidentally confuse them.

Comment: Nice answer. But can you tell the difference between const-version and non-const version ? When would I use either of them ?

Comment: Also why it is needed to overload `->` and `*`. Why is just overloading `->` not enough ?

Comment: @SimpleGuy Users of your class generally expect `foo->bar` to be equivalent to `(*foo).bar`. Having them different will shock many people.

Comment: @Bernard Oh.. from that perspective it is good to do so..

Answer (score 5):

Overload the `->` operator:

```
template <typename T> class MyClass
{
    T * p;
public:
    T       * operator->()       { return p; }  // #1
    T const * operator->() const { return p; }
};
```

Note that *both* overloads don't mutate the object; nonetheless we decide to make #1 non-const, so that we bequeath constness of the object onto the pointee. This is sometimes called "deep constness propagation" or something of this sort. The language D takes this much further.

Comment: "we decide to make #1 non-const" -- at least, we can if we want to. Standard smart pointers don't, essentially for the same reason that it's possible to modify an object of type `T` via a `T *const`. Which you do depends whether `instance` is "logically" an indirect reference to the other object (in which case imitate standard smart pointers) or not (in which case curse Bjarne that you can't overload `operator.`).

Comment: @SteveJessop: "We" as in "you and I, on this journey into C++", rather than "we the extant rulers of all opinion", I suppose. Sorry, old habits :-)

Answer (score 3):

The member access operator can be overloaded to return a pointer to the object to be accessed:

```
T * operator->() {return ptr;}
T const * operator->() const {return ptr;}
```

You might also want the deference operator, to make it feel even more like a pointer; this returns a reference instead:

```
T & operator*() {return *ptr;}
T const & operator*() const {return *ptr;}
```